# Import 2 materials into a single slot

Tags: texturing, shaders

Does anyone know how to import a material into an existing slot.
The goal is to use a downloaded 2 materials.
I would like to use it with a Mix Shader so I can use the FAC to create a pattern within a specific area of the geometry.
This is a single object, the topology is not setup so that I can assign materials to faces.
Currently the only method I have discovered is to Group all the nodes behind the Material Output node.
I can then use ADD to add the Group into the Slot that I want to import the material into.
Is this the only method?

Comment: Yes you can do it this way, then you can ungroup if the group bothers you